# Having an error with the Text function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, text

So i started learning Kotlin,and im following the android studio course, and now i have to build a simple app, but something with the Text function is wrong

i have thois code

```
package com.example.finaltask

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.finaltask.ui.theme.FinalTaskTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FinalTaskTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    ArtTaskCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ArtTaskCompleted() {
    TaskCompleted(
        stringResource(R.string.title),
        stringResource(R.string.description),

    )
}

@Composable
fun TaskCompleted(
    title: String,
    description: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        val img = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_task_completed)
        Image(
            painter = img,
            contentDescription = null
        )

        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = modifier.padding(top = 24.dp, bottom = 8.dp),
            FontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )

        Text(
            text = description,
            modifier = modifier.padding(10.dp),
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    FinalTaskTheme {
        ArtTaskCompleted()
    }
}
```

In the second Text shows this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bFcn.png)

Is the second time this happend, before i just cut the piece of code and pasted again and it worked, but now there is no way, i checked the solution in the github they provide and is the same

Does anyone had this erro before?

Is this a configuration error?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is due to the name of the property you provided.

The text composable function takes the following parameters.

```
@Composable
fun Text(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    inlineContent: Map<String, InlineTextContent> = mapOf(),
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
): Unit
```

You must give the **FontWeight** value you have given as **fontWeight**.

My answer supports fshd19's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold` instead of `FontWeight = FontWeight.Bold`